# Convert array to string from Object.values nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var body = request.body;
for (var i = 0; i < body.data.length; i++) {
 var obj = body.data[i];
 var keys = Object.keys(obj);
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var value = Object.values(obj[keys[i]]);
  console.log(value);
 }
}
```

In here i'm get reponse like this `[{key: 'key'}, {key1: 'key1'}]`

And how to convert `[{key: 'key'}, {key1: 'key1'}]` to `{key: 'key'}, {key1: 'key1'}`

I'm try `Object.values(obj[keys[i]]).join();` but the response like this `(Object, Object), (Object, Object)`

Comment: Just use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: When just `JSON.stringify(value);` the response like this `[{"key": "key"}, {"key1": "key"'}]`

Comment: `{key: 'key'}, {key1: 'key1'}` is not valid. Either it has to be in an array like before or like  `"masterKey":{ "randomString": {key: 'key'}, "randomString2": {key1: 'key1'}}`

Comment: My request body like this boy `{"data": [{"key": "key"}, {"key1": "key"'}]` and no problem when parse data value.